# Unable to udnerstand Big O notation examples

Tags: big-o

How they are calculating Big O notation?

Big O notation examples:

1. Question:
   Find upper bound for f(n) = n⁴ + 100n² + 50

   Solution:
   n⁴ + 100n² + 50 <= 2n⁴, for all n >= 11
   n⁴ + 100n² + 50 = O(n⁴) with c = 2 and n<sub>0</sub> = 11

   I am unable to understand - how they are calculating Big O notation?
   How come c = 2 and n<sub>0</sub> = 11
2. Question:
   Find upper bound for f(n) = 2n³ - 2n²

   Solution:
   2n³ - 2n² <= 2n³ , for all n >= 1
   2n³ - 2n² = O(2n³) with c = 2 and n<sub>0</sub> =1

   How come n >= 1?
3. Question:
   f(n) = n

   Solution :
   n <= n , for all n >= 1
   N = O(n) with c = 1 and n<sub>0</sub> = 1

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**

[Definition of big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) is (note that the wikipedia definition uses `x0` and `M`, there is no real difference, just different signs for the same things).

f(n) is said to be in O(g(n)) if there are constants `n0` and `c` such that for all `n>n0` - `f(n) <= c*g(n)`.

In your example, since `n^4+100n^2+50 <= 2n^4` for all `n>11`, it is basically same as saying the above with `c=2,n0=11` - thus, by definition of big O notation, you could say `n^4+100n^2+50` is in `O(n^4)`

**Question 2:**

In here, `n>=1` because the claim is true for all positive values of `n` - note that `2n^3-2n^2` will always be smaller than `2n^3` - for all positive values of `n`.